# Find a function $f\not \in BV[0,1]$ and $|f|\in BV[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Find a function $f\not \in BV[0,1]$ and $|f|\in BV[0,1]$

I was thinking in a bounded function |f| such that f isn't bounded, but this isn't possible. Moreover, i'm trying to construct another pairwise function, but i'm a little stuck. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

How about $f(x) = 1$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x) = -1$ otherwise?

Comment: Okay, this implies: $|f|$ in $BV[0,1]$ because $|f|$ is the constant $|f|$ is absolutly continous.  Moreover, why $f\not \in BV[0,1]$? i don't see that part.

Comment: Sure. First, can you tell me what it means for a function $f$ to have bounded variation?

Comment: Yes, $Var(f,P;[a,b])=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}|f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})|$ then f $\in BV[a,b]$ if $\sup\{Var(f,P;[a,b])\}: P\in \mathbb{P}[a,b]\}<\infty$

Comment: That's not quite right, but think about this: what if $P$ partitions $[a,b]$ into 299,792,458 subintervals each of which has one rational endpoint and one irrational endpoint? What will be the value of $\sum_{i=1}^m |f(t_i) - f(t_{i-1})|$? What if the number of subintervals increases?